# What is the next step in this algebra problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the function $$f(x)=\frac{2x^3+x^2+1}{x^2-1}$$
For which values of $y$ can the equation $y=f(x)$ be solved ?. Teacher's note:It is not necessary to find the explicit solutions of the equation.
Here is what I've done. We have the expression $$y=\frac{2x^3+x^2+1}{x^2-1}$$
I changed the $x$ to the $y$, to find the domain of the inverse which will give me the answer that I'm looking for so $$x=\frac{2y^3+y^2+1}{y^2-1}$$ I move all the expression to one side to make it equal zero $$y^2x-x-2y^3-y^2-1=0$$
What do I do next how do I find the values ?.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top and bottom of f(x) can be divided by the factor (x+1), as shown above.  However, the remaining reduced expression for f(x) has a "hole" in it at x=-1 (i.e., x=-1 is not part of the domain of f(x)).  The remaining expression has a vertical asymptote at x=1.  Plotting the reduced version of f(x) shows that there is local minimum value to the right of x=1 and a local maximum to the left of the vertical asymptote at x=1.  Using calculus, we can set the first derivative of the reduced version of f(x) = 0 to find these two local extrema:

df/dx = 0 = (2x^2 - 4x) / (x-1)^2

0 = 2x(x-2)    ==>    x=0 and x=2

Plugging in to f(x) gives the points (0,-1), and (2,7) as the local max and min values.

Examination of the graph shows that y can take on any value from negative infinity to positive infinity with the exception of values between -1 and 7.  And also the value of y= -2 is not allowed (due to the hole).  So the final solution is:

y <= -1  OR y >= 7  AND also y cannot = -2

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking too hard. Solving $f(x) = y$ means there is a point $x$ so that $f(x)$ is equal to $y$. Think about the graph of the polynomial $2x^3+x^2 + 1$. Are there any points on the $y$ axis it *doesn't* hit? What changes when we have the denominator $x^2 -1$?

Answer (score 1):

Easy to see that $-1$ is a root of $2x^3+x^2+1=0$, so we could refactor it as:

$$y=\frac{(x+1)(2x^2-x+1)}{(x+1)(x-1)}=\frac{2x^2-x+1}{x-1}$$

Thus

$$2x^2-(y+1)x+(1-y)=0$$

Now you should be able to express $x$ with $y$. Notice that it is guaranteed that $x \ne -1$. Also check the $\Delta$ if you want the solution of $x$ to be real numbers.